# ReBoot Rasperry 3 from SD, after putting the card in a RaspPi4 by mistake

Tags: boot

I've got a problem and I really hope it's just a small step for you, but a big leap for mankind, or at least for me.

I have a Rasberry3 working very fine on a SDCard. I bought a new Raspberry4, of course without reading about the "dont put your Raspb3 SD-Card into the 4"-part.

So I dit. It didn't start. Of course.

Putting back the card into the Rasp3. Didn't restart either.

So here's the question:

What did the Rasp4 do to the SD card, while it was trying to boot. Did it change boot settings or other data, like owner settings of certain files? I need to get that card on the Rasp3 rerunning, and I dont have a monitor or keyboard for it, so see whats going on while booting. Only the filesystem and a linux terminal to write on that SD. So I really hope that somebody knows what the bootloader did on the filesystem, while he was trying to boot on the raspberry4.

thank you :)

Comment: What happened on the Pi4?

Comment: If you pulled the power on the RPi4 you may have left the filesystems on the SDCard with the dirty bit set. Build a new Raspbian Buster SDCard as a rescue system. Run `sudo fsck -f -y ...` for every partition on the non-bootable card. Then when you're done use that rescue system SDCard to boot your RPi4.